# systemd-journald and rsyslogd: high cpu usage

Tags: debian, syslog, rsyslog, systemd-journald, iwlwifi

This is a fresh Debian 10 installation that's two-three weeks old.

For the last couple of days, my system has been acting up, it would just slow down and I would not be able to use `sudo` in the terminal as it won't prompt for authentication. When I check CPU usage using `htop`, it shows that `systemd-journald` is using quite a lot of CPU, more than 100%. One time there was two or three processes/thread of `rsyslogd` using around 50% CPU each. I haven't seen `rsyslogd` using that much CPU after that.

Since I could not use `sudo`, I wasn't able to check the logs, but today I found out that I could just `su` and become root while `sudo` wasn't working and I checked the logs.

The following is an excerpt from `journalctl`:

```
Aug 25 22:27:34 asgard systemd-journald[2471]: Missed 51 kernel messages
Aug 25 22:27:34 asgard kernel: wlp0s20f3:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
Aug 25 22:27:34 asgard kernel: WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2221 at net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:19 drv_sta_state+0x265/0x3e0 [mac80211]
Aug 25 22:27:34 asgard systemd-journald[2471]: Missed 56 kernel messages
Aug 25 22:27:34 asgard kernel:  drbg ansi_cprng cfg80211 dell_rbtn processor_thermal_device iTCO_vendor_support irqbypass intel_soc_dts_iosf ecdh_generic sg joydev dell_laptop hid_multitouch idma64 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul int3403_thermal rfkill int3400_thermal int340x_thermal_zone wmi_bmof dell_smo8800 dell_wmi intel_hid pcc_cpufreq dell_smbios dell_smm_hwmon dcdbas intel_pch_thermal ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi dell_wmi_descriptor typec acpi_thermal_rel evdev sparse_keymap pcspkr serio_raw ghash_clmulni_intel acpi_tad acpi_pad ac intel_cstate intel_uncore xt_conntrack nft_compat intel_rapl_perf efi_pstore efivars battery nft_counter nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables nfnetlink efivarfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4
```

And the following part from `journalctl` is all over the log:

```
Aug 25 22:27:34 asgard systemd-journald[2471]: Missed 55 kernel messages
Aug 25 22:27:34 asgard kernel:  crc16 mbcache jbd2 fscrypto ecb btrfs xor zstd_decompress zstd_compress xxhash raid6_pq libcrc32c crc32c_generic sd_mod hid_generic crc32c_intel i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core i915 psmouse aesni_intel xhci_pci aes_x86_64 crypto_simd xhci_hcd cryptd glue_helper i2c_i801 ahci libahci libata i2c_algo_bit usbcore r8169 drm_kms_helper realtek sdhci_pci libphy cqhci scsi_mod sdhci drm mmc_core intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss mfd_core usb_common i2c_hid hid wmi video button
```

From `dmesg`:

```
[ 2420.057787] wlp0s20f3:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[ 2420.057800] Modules linked in: uinput cmac rfcomm bnep ctr ccm fuse binfmt_misc nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nls_ascii snd_soc_skl nls_cp437 vfat fat xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi nf_log_ipv4 snd_hda_codec_realtek nf_log_common snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_generic ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 snd_compress xt_LOG snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm uvcvideo intel_rapl snd_timer snd x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp nft_limit coretemp videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common kvm_intel videodev iTCO_wdt soundcore xt_limit arc4 media iwlmvm mac80211 btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth xt_addrtype kvm iwlwifi xt_tcpudp mei_me mei
[ 2420.057845] RSP: 0018:ffffbfd40269f9b0 EFLAGS: 00010282
[ 2420.057850] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9f0f26200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 2420.057879]  __sta_info_flush+0x15e/0x1c0 [mac80211]
[ 2420.057892]  ieee80211_set_disassoc+0xbe/0x550 [mac80211]
[ 2420.057903]  ieee80211_mgd_deauth.cold.57+0x47/0x1b5 [mac80211]
[ 2420.057914]  cfg80211_mlme_deauth+0xb3/0x1d0 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.057926]  cfg80211_mlme_down+0x66/0x90 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.057937]  cfg80211_disconnect+0x128/0x1e0 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.057946]  cfg80211_leave+0x26/0x40 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.057954]  cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0xcd/0x600 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.057956]  ? syscall_return_via_sysret+0x14/0x83
[ 2420.057957]  ? ret_from_fork+0x1a/0x40
[ 2420.057970]  ? ieee80211_reconfig+0xd5/0x1420 [mac80211]
[ 2420.057984]  ? report_bug+0xb0/0xd0
[ 2420.057985]  ? inetdev_event+0x46/0x580
[ 2420.057988]  notifier_call_chain+0x47/0x70
[ 2420.057992]  dev_close_many+0x9f/0x160
[ 2420.058002]  cfg80211_shutdown_all_interfaces+0x6d/0xc0 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.058015]  ? rcu_exp_wait_wake+0x250/0x250
[ 2420.058016]  ? try_to_del_timer_sync+0x4d/0x80
[ 2420.058028]  process_one_work+0x1a7/0x3a0
[ 2420.058030]  worker_thread+0x30/0x390
[ 2420.058031]  ? create_worker+0x1a0/0x1a0
[ 2420.058035]  ? kthread_bind+0x30/0x30
[ 2420.058043] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 2420.058056] Modules linked in: uinput cmac rfcomm bnep ctr ccm fuse binfmt_misc nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nls_ascii snd_soc_skl nls_cp437 vfat fat xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi nf_log_ipv4 snd_hda_codec_realtek nf_log_common snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_generic ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 snd_compress xt_LOG snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm uvcvideo intel_rapl snd_timer snd x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp nft_limit coretemp videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common kvm_intel videodev iTCO_wdt soundcore xt_limit arc4 media iwlmvm mac80211 btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth xt_addrtype kvm iwlwifi xt_tcpudp mei_me mei
[ 2420.058101] RSP: 0018:ffffbfd40269f9b0 EFLAGS: 00010282
[ 2420.058107] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9f0f26200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 2420.058136]  __sta_info_flush+0x15e/0x1c0 [mac80211]
[ 2420.058147]  ieee80211_set_disassoc+0xbe/0x550 [mac80211]
[ 2420.058159]  ieee80211_mgd_deauth.cold.57+0x47/0x1b5 [mac80211]
[ 2420.058170]  cfg80211_mlme_deauth+0xb3/0x1d0 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.058181]  cfg80211_mlme_down+0x66/0x90 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.058193]  cfg80211_disconnect+0x128/0x1e0 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.058202]  cfg80211_leave+0x26/0x40 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.058210]  cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0xcd/0x600 [cfg80211]
[ 2420.058212]  ? syscall_return_via_sysret+0x14/0x83
[ 2420.058213]  ? ret_from_fork+0x1a/0x40
[ 2420.058238]  ? ieee80211_reconfig+0xd5/0x1420 [mac80211]
[ 2420.058240]  ? report_bug+0xb0/0xd0
[ 2420.058241]  ? inetdev_event+0x46/0x580
[ 2420.058245]  notifier_call_chain+0x47/0x70
[ 2420.058248]  dev_close_many+0x9f/0x160
[ 2420.058269]  ieee80211_reconfig+0xa3/0x1420 [mac80211]
[ 2420.058271]  ? rcu_exp_wait_wake+0x250/0x250
[ 2420.058272]  ? try_to_del_timer_sync+0x4d/0x80
[ 2420.058285]  worker_thread+0x30/0x390
[ 2420.058288]  kthread+0x112/0x130
[ 2420.058291]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
[ 2420.058298] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

Similar to `journalctl` messages, the above logs from `dmesg` were also repeated endlessly in the `dmesg`. (I think these `dmesg` logs were displayed as I tried to shutdown the system when the system hangs, but I couldn't make sure as the messages were rapidly moving.)

I thing the slow down is caused by excessive logging as `/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` are about 23GB each.

I am not sure what causes this much errors/logs, but I suspect it's the wi-fi of the laptop. The WiFi  chip is an `Intel® Wireless-AC 9560` and I have been having some connection issues with wifi. (The wifi would disconnect all of a sudden and the network manager would show `device is not ready`. When I reboot, the wifi option is gone from Network manager. This has occurred twice and toggling the `Secure Boot` in `UEFI` to `OFF/ON` would fix it.)

I didn't notice any trouble with wifi when the system became slow.

- Here's another related question from Askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251908/syslog-and-kern-log-keeps-filling-up-and-network-stops-working
- A bug report from Red Hat: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1851185
- An Ubuntu Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1882419/comments/12
- Bug report from Linux Kernal: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98321

What exactly is happening here and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and checked frequently for a response. As of the September 26th update, the issue seems to be resolved.